# A surprising result about the product of Blaschke matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, recurrence-relations

I have verified analytically the conjecture described bellow up to $n=4$, but have had no success trying to prove it. Any help would be much appreciated.

---

**Setup**

Let $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be real numbers and $g_i:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ for all $i\in \mathbb N $. Consider the following recurrence

$$ g_{i+1}(x)=\frac{1+g_{i}(\lambda_{i})g_{i}(x)}{g_{i}(\lambda_{i})-g_{i}(x)}\frac{x-\lambda_{i}}{1-\lambda_{i}x}. $$

with

$$ g_1(x) = a+bx .$$

Next, let

$$ \mathbf M_i(x) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{x-\lambda_i}{1-\lambda_i x}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} g_i(\lambda_i) & -1 \\ 1 & g_i(\lambda_i)\end{bmatrix}, $$

and

$$ S(x) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} g_{n+1}(0) & -1 \\ 1 & g_{n+1}(0)\end{bmatrix}\left[\mathbf M_n(x)\mathbf M_{n-1}(x)\dots\mathbf M_{2}(x)\mathbf M_1(x)\right]\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

---

**Conjecture**

> For all $n\ge 2$ and for all $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, $$\frac{S(\lambda_i)}{S(\lambda_j)} = \frac{\lambda_j\left(1+g_1(\lambda_j)g_1(1/\lambda_j)\right)}{\lambda_i\left(1+g_1(\lambda_i)g_1(1/\lambda_i)\right)}.$$

---

The reason I consider this surprising is that the analytical formulas for $S(x)$ become extremely complicated very quickly as $n$ increases, yet these ratios continue to satisfy this simple equation.

---

**Background**

The motivation for this question comes from the following. Suppose $\mathbf A (x)$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix such that $\det (\mathbf A (x))$ has $n+1$ roots (inside the unit circle): $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $0$.

To solve some forecasting problems (in which $\mathbf A (x)$ represents the signal structure) it is useful to find a matrix $\mathbf B (x)$ such that $\det(\mathbf A (x)\mathbf B (x))$ has no roots (inside the unit circle).

A procedure to obtain the matrix $\mathbf B (x)$ is as follows. To remove the first root, $\lambda_1$, you multiply $\mathbf A (x)$ by an unitary matrix times the Blaschke matrix for this root, i.e.

$$ \mathbf A^* (x) = \mathbf A (x) \mathbf W_1 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{x-\lambda_1}{1-\lambda_1 x}\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\mathbf W_1$ is a matrix whose columns are the left singular vectors of the of $\mathbf A(\lambda_1)$. To remove the second root, $\lambda_2$, you repeat this step using $\mathbf A^*(x)$ instead of $\mathbf A(x)$. Then, one can simply repeat this step for each of the other roots.

The matrices $\mathbf M_i(x)$ above are (up to a constant), the transpose of the matrices that are multiplied to $\mathbf A^*(x)$ in each step described above. One simplifying aspect of the problem I am working with is that the second row of $\mathbf A(x)$ is equal to $0$ when evaluated at any of the roots.

Comment: where does all this come from ? oO

Comment: @mercio To forecast some stochastic variable given a signal structure, it is useful to first remove the roots of the signal structure that are inside the unit circle. The matrices above are what you need to multiply the signal structure by to remove $n$ roots plus a root at $0$.

Comment: @mercio I added some background to the problem that hopefully clarifies a bit more where it comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon setting $\lambda_{n+1}=0$, we see that
$$S(x) = \frac{1}{x}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\left[\mathbf M_{n+1}(x)\mathbf M_n(x)\mathbf M_{n-1}(x)\dots\mathbf M_{2}(x)\mathbf M_1(x)\right]\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Thus (working with $n$ instead of $n+1$), we see that we have to control the lower right entry of $$\mathbf M(x)=\mathbf M_n(x)\mathbf M_{n-1}(x)\dots\mathbf M_{2}(x)\mathbf M_1(x).$$

By induction, one verifies that $g_i(\lambda_i)-g_i(x)$ is a scalar multiple (factor depending on $i$) of $\frac{x-\lambda_i}{1-x\lambda_{i-1}}$ for $i\ge 2$. Set $$\Gamma(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{x-\lambda_i}{1-x\lambda_i}\text{ and }g(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(g_i(\lambda_i)-g_i(x)).$$ Thus
$$
g(x)=c\Gamma(x)(1-x\lambda_n)\tag{1}
$$
for a constant $c$.

In the following, we drop the argument $x$ if the meaning is clear. From the recursion for $g_i$ we obtain
$$\mathbf M_i\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ g_i\end{bmatrix}=(g_i(\lambda_i)-g_i(x))\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ g_{i+1}\end{bmatrix}.$$ Iterated application yields $$\mathbf M\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ g_1\end{bmatrix}=g\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ g_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}.\tag{2}$$

For a term $A$ in $x$ define $\tilde A$ by $\tilde A(x)=A(1/x)$. Then
$$\tilde{\mathbf M}_i^t\mathbf M_i=(g_i(\lambda_i)^2+1)\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},$$ hence $$\tilde{\mathbf M}^t\mathbf M=\gamma\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},$$ where $$\gamma=\prod_{i=1}^n(g_i(\lambda_i)^2+1).$$ Now we apply the tilde transformation to equation (2):
$$\tilde{\mathbf M}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \tilde g_1\end{bmatrix}=\tilde g\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \tilde g_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}.$$ Transposing and multiplying from the right with $M$ yields
$$\gamma\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \tilde g_1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \tilde g_1 \end{bmatrix}\tilde{\mathbf M}^t\mathbf M=\tilde g\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \tilde g_{n+1} \end{bmatrix}\mathbf M.$$ Together with the previous relation (2) for $\mathbf M$ we obtain four linear equations for the four entries of $\mathbf M=\begin{bmatrix} m_1 & m_2\\ m_3 & m_4 \end{bmatrix}$ in terms of $\gamma,g_1,\tilde g_1,g_{n+1},\tilde g_{n+1},g,\tilde g$, namely
\begin{align*}
m_1+m_2g_1&=g\\
m_3+m_4g_1&=gg_{n+1}\\
m_1\tilde g+m_3\tilde g_{n+1}\tilde gt&=\gamma\\
m_2\tilde g+m_4\tilde g_{n+1}\tilde g&=\tilde g_1\gamma.
\end{align*}
The rank of the system is $3$. Use the first, second and fourth equation to express $m_1,m_2,m_3$ in terms of $m_4$. As expected, the third equation does not allow to solve for $m_4$, rather it collapses to
$$(g_{n+1}\tilde g_{n+1} + 1)g\tilde g=(g_1\tilde g_1+1)\gamma,\tag{3}$$
a relation we will need in a moment.

We can determine $m_4$ from
$$m_1m_4-m_2m_3=\det\mathbf M=\gamma\Gamma(x)$$ and obtain
$$
m_4(x)=\frac{(g\tilde g_1g_{n+1} + \tilde g\Gamma)\gamma}{(g_{n+1}\tilde g_{n+1} + 1)g\tilde g}.$$

Together with (3) this gives
$$m_4(x)=\frac{g\tilde g_1g_{n+1} + \tilde g\Gamma}{g_1\tilde g_1 + 1}.$$

For $1\le i\le n-1$ we have $g(\lambda_i)=0$, and $\lambda_i$ is not a pole of $\tilde g_1$, nor of $g_{n+1}$.

However, $\lambda_i$ is a root of $\Gamma$, and potentially a pole of $\tilde g$. So in order to evaluate $\tilde g\Gamma$ in $\lambda_i$ we apply the tilde operation to equation (1) and obtain $$\tilde g=c\tilde\Gamma\left(1-\frac{\lambda_n}{x}\right).$$

It follows from the definition of $\Gamma$ that $\tilde\Gamma\Gamma=1$, hence $$\tilde g\Gamma=c\frac{x-\lambda_n}{x}.$$

Now we can evaluate in $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$, and obtain
$$
\frac{m_4(\lambda_i)}{m_4(\lambda_j)}
=\frac{\lambda_j\;(g_1(\lambda_j)g_1(1/\lambda_j) + 1)\;(\lambda_n - \lambda_i)}{\lambda_i\;(g_1(\lambda_i)g_1(1/\lambda_i) + 1)\;(\lambda_n - \lambda_j)}.$$
Thus, as explained in the beginning, with $\lambda_n=0$ we get the case $n-1$ of the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, this is incredible! I hope you don't mind a fixed a small typo in equation (1).

Comment: @mzp: You are welcome, and thanks for spotting and fixing the typos.